# Efficently querying multi language categories and category items

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a bit of a server response time issue - which I think is caused due to obsolete queries. One major query chain that I have takes up to 370ms, which is obviously causing an issue.

**Here are the requirements:**

1. 5 Different languages
2. There are several Product Categories (i.e. Cat 1, Cat 2, Cat 3, etc.)
3. Categories displayed depend on language. For example whilst category 1 is displayed in all languages, category 2 is only displayed in Germany and France but not in the UK
4. Each category contains x number of items (**has_many belongs_to relationship**). Again some items are displayed in certain languages others are not. For example even category 2 is displayed in France and Germany, only in Germany you can buy Item 1 and hence Item 1 should not be displayed in France but Germany.
5. The categories and items do have boolean fields named after the locale. This way I can set via flag whether or not to display the category and item in a specific language.

**My solution:**

Building the solution is quiet easy. In controller I read out all the categories for the current locale:

*application_controller.rb (since it is used on every single page)*

---

```
@product_categories = ProductCategory.where("lang_" + I18n.locale.to_s + " = ?", true)
```

---

And in the view (the navigation) I do the following:

*layouts/navs/productnav.html.haml*

---

```
- @product_categories.each do |category|
  ...
  - category.products.includes(:product_teasers).where("lang_" + I18n.locale.to_s + " = ? AND active = ?", true, true).in_groups_of(3).each do |group|
    ...
```

---

The issue with this solution is that each time I fire a lot of queries towards the database. Using "includes" does not solve it as I can not specify what items to pull. Furthermore I require the in_groups_of(3) in my loop to display the items correctly on the page.

I was also looking into memchached solutions to have the queries cached all together - i.e. [Dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) however, this would require me to change a lot of code as I am guessing I would require to query all categories for each language and cache them. In addition to it I have to query each item for each langugage depending on language and store that somehow in an array ?!

**My question:**

How to approach this ? There must be a simpler and more efficient solution. How to efficiently query respectively cache this?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

As requested here are my two Models:

1.) ProductCategory

```
class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :name, :description, :slug, :meta_keywords, :meta_description, :meta_title, :header, :teaser, :fallbacks_for_empty_translations => true
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => [:globalize, :slugged]
  globalize_accessors :locales => [:at, :de, :ch_de, :ch_fr, :fr, :int_en, :int_fr], :attributes => [:slug]

  has_paper_trail
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  default_scope { includes(:translations) }

  private
  def slug_candidates
    [
        [:name]
    ]
  end
end
```

2.) Product
And every product Category can have 0..n Products, and each Product must belongs to one category.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :slug, :name, :meta_keywords, :meta_description, :meta_title, :teaser, :power_range, :product_page_teaser, :product_category_slider_teaser, :fallbacks_for_empty_translations => true
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, :use => :globalize

  before_save :change_file_name

  searchable do
    text :name, :teaser, :product_page_teaser, :product_category_slider_teaser
    integer :product_category_id
  end

  belongs_to :product_category
  has_many :product_teasers, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :product_videos, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :product_banners, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :product_documents, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :product_tabs, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
           foreign_key: "follower_id",
           dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
           foreign_key: "followed_id",
           dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
  has_many :references

  has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_teasers, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_tabs, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_videos, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_banners, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_documents, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

  has_paper_trail
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  default_scope {includes(:translations)}

  .... a lot more going on here ...

end
```

Please note: That category contains language flags (booleans), i.e lang_at, lang_de, lang_fr, etc. and if set then this category is displayed in that particualar language. SAME applies to products, as certain products are not displayed in all langauges altough the category might be.

Examples:

```
@product_categories = ProductCategory.where("product_categories.lang_" + I18n.locale.to_s + " = ?", true)

@products = Product.where("product_categories.lang_" + I18n.locale.to_s + " = ?", true)
```

I skipped any includes on purpose above - it is just to demonstrate the language logic.

Comment: can you show the model? I need to know your associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The system have spent a lot of times to loop data in nested loop. Avoid to fetch data in nested loop. You have to use join or includes to catch your data more effective. For example:

**Controller**

```
@products = Product.includes(:product_category).where("product_categories.lang_" + I18n.locale.to_s + " = ? AND product_categories.active = ?", true, true).group_by(&:category)
```

**View**

```
- @products.each do |category, products|
  <%= category.name %>
  - products.each do |product|
    <%= product.title %>
```

It needs to fix with your necessary code. I just help the main query. For example: `active = ?` is for products field or product_categories field. I hope It can help you.

Comment: Hi Muhamad, sorry haven't seen your response before. I am going to update my question shortly with my Models - I tried this approach before, however my join seems to terribly fail somewhat as both Categories and Products itself are language dependent. Anyway, will update shortly and thank you !

Comment: @GeorgKeferböck, I have done to update my code. It should be checked again based on your requirements. Let me know the result.

Comment: Brilliant, that did the trick - another 495ms saved. Good thing is - that caused me to work a lot with caching and use of wiselinks - I initially made the mistake of grouping it wrong. Well, now I am down to a speed of 230ms on average .. and that is fast considering what's going on, on that page ! Yay! Thanks again for your time & help !